# What to write as an URL in RESTful API in Android

Tags: android, asp.net, rest

I have developed a RESTful API using ASP.NET. 
When I run the ASP.NET application I get an URL like this :

http://localhost:12345/Handler1.ashx

I don't know what URL to write in RestAPI.java in Android. I have tried these but none of them worked :

> http://localhost:12345/Handler1.ashx
>
> http://10.0.0.77:12345/Handler1.ashx (10.0.0.77 is my local IP)
>
> http://10.0.2.2:12345/Handler1.ashx

Right now Visual Studio project is running. But I cannot connect to Restful web service from Android emulator or browser. Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the emulator or your phone?

Comment: @Benten emulator. And I'm running web service on my machine, not in any IIS server.